# php, Showing the first row only of mysqli query results

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently working on creating a Real Estate Ads Script
On the User Show page, I wanted to show the user-added ads, and I ran into a problem, which was to show only the first ad added by the user. The problem is not in a query mysqli nor while, I was print array using print_r function was printed first advertisement only, and I calculated the number of query results by mysqli_num_rows() function which is 8, and i used functions mysqli_fetch_array and mysqli_fetch_assoc and mysqli_fetch_row and all of them did not solve my problem
Please solve this problem because I am late on the client in creating the site
Code
https://evotecpro.com/code.html

Comment: Yeah, don't send us to see your code, if you want to get help - Include the code in your post

Comment: you need to iterate while in `mysqli_fetch_array()`

Comment: The linked script also is not a minimal example. You should provide as little code as needed to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: You do not provide enough to answer properly.  But here are some suggestins.  Ensure your query returns only 1 result, the one you want.  To do this, sort via the posted date or something like that and limit to the first result.  Then when you do mysqli_fetch_array once, you will get the first result you want.  And **please** read the help on how to post good questions (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Vipul Lakhtariya I didn't understand, what do you mean

Comment: @Rakanalzahrani 
`$fulldata = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query) ){
    $fulldata[] = $row[0];
}
`

Comment: @Vipul Lakhtariya I still don't understand, what's the use of fulldata var?

Answer (score 1):

you need used to    `mysqli_fetch_all()`.
And you can see this tutorial more info about the `fetch_all()` function 
[PHP mysqli_fetch_all() Function - W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_all.asp)

Comment: I not have mysqlnd, what can i do?

Comment: @Alon Eitan i try to include the code, but i could not include it